# Is there a way to communicate between two cluster workers directly in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cluster-computing

I know a master can send messages to workers/workers to master but is there a way to do the direct worker-to-worker communication in nodejs cluster?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know is to emit an event from the worker to the master, then to echo back the event from the master to the other workers